# Why does google use 1000 char long image links?

Tags: google-search, links, images

When I copy an image address from the gallery on `google.fr/images` it copies this to my clipboard, why?

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

It's a bit overkill for a hyperlink? what is google doing? I know that if I click on it again I get the real link, but it's a new thing from Google, it's weird!

Comment: not rly, this isn't a "link" its the image translated to symbols/characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As You can see from the prefix it's JPEG file encoded by base64 binary-to-text encoding scheme. So, it's not a hyperlink but the whole file instead.

Technically, You could use this in HTML, CSS, etc to save some extra requests and/or issues with offsite resource not being available anymore.

Various browsers and scrapers used to use that just to download the view of some web-page in single file.

Some random HTML example from the widths of the internet:

```
<img width="16" height="16" alt="star" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7" />
```

Comment: This also gives you the ability to do an Google image search with an uploaded picture, then sent someone the link (or post it on social media), for someone else to see the same results without having access to the original image file.